# Conditionally change font color of number passed from pythontex

Tags: xetex, conditionals, python

I would like to color numbers red if they are less than zero. In my final report, these number will be generated from a python script. To use the pythontex package, I first run `xelatex doc.tex`, then `pythontex doc.tex`, and then `xelatex doc.tex` one last time for the python script to run and its contents imported into my document.

Unfortunately, during this process, the first xelatex command throws an error because `\py{2-4}` hasn't been generated yet, so the `\colorme` command I created is being passed a `?` as an argument and not a number.

Is there anyway around this? All I want to do is change the color of the number based on whether its greater than zero or not?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\colorme}[1]{\ifnum #1 > 0
        #1
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1}
    \fi
}


\begin{document}

    \colorme{5} %success
    \colorme{-1} %success
    \colorme{\py{2-4}} %fails

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Makes sense. I made the appropriate changes

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding a default number:

```
\newcommand{\colorme}[1]{\ifnum 0 < 0#1
        #1 \%
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1 \%} 
    \fi
}
```